# document.getElementById to $

Tags: javascript, jquery

I found a little chat script and thought Id try to minimize the javascript a little and tried to change `document.getElementById` to `$` and `.value` to `.val()`

```
function chat_initial(){
    var user = document.getElementById('chat_user').value;

    // tried to change above line to this
    // var user = $('chat_user').val();

    $.post('chat.php', {stage:'initial',user:user}, function(data){
        if (data == 'good'){

            chat_load();
            running = true;

            $('#chatbox #initial').css('display', 'none');
            $('#chatbox #primary').css('display', 'inline');
        }
        else
            alert('That username is taken. Please try another.');
    });
}
```

but when I did the script no longer worked, it just keeps popping up the `alert()` message, what have I done wrong?

jquery is loaded so I assumed it would work.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/

Comment: `$` is not equivalent to `document.getElementById` - it is the jQuery function that allows you to manipulate the DOM - passing a string tells jQuery you're querying the DOM based on the string. To declare that you want to find an element by id, you need to use "#" first. Here are all possible selectors: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/?rdfrom=http%3A%2F%2Fdocs.jquery.com%2Fmw%2Findex.php%3Ftitle%3DSelectors%26redirect%3Dno

Comment: @ianpgall "*passing a string tells jQuery you're querying the DOM based on the string*" - you can also pass a string representing HTML source code, which is then parsed. So, there are two usages for `$( string )`.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas Crap, you're right. Thanks for pointing that out, I guess that slipped my mind for this application. I guess technically it can be HTML or XML

Comment: I think this could be a good link for this as well: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/

Comment: Forgot the #hash, don't you just hate it when its something so simple that's starring you in the face lol thanks all

Answer (score 3):

This will work:

```
$('#chat_user').val();
```

(You need to tell jQuery that you're doing an ID query. You do that by prefixing the ID-string with `"#"`.)

Answer (score 0):

CSS3 selector in jQuery does the trick!
`#` Selects an element by it's ID attribute
`.` Selects elements by their class tag

So to get your code working, you'll need to type the selector along with the `$()` like so:

```
$("#chat_user")
```

And to select the value of the DOM-tag (input tag probably?) We type [.val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/):

```
$("#chat_user").val()
```

I hope that sorted it!

Comment: Neither ID nor class are CSS3